# How do access my flask app hosted in docker?

Tags: python, bash, docker, flask, dockerfile

I am dockerizing my flask app for the first time, but I'm having an issue accessing it, these are steps I followed

my docker file looks like this

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev


# We copy just the requirements.txt first to leverage Docker cache
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]

CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Generated requirements through pip3 freeze command

```
sp@sp-H81M-S:~/Desktop/flask_app$ sudo docker build -t fynd_task_app:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  297.5MB
Step 1/8 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> a2a15febcdf3
Step 2/8 : RUN apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d9f20954e3a8
Step 3/8 : COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 37dd9000750d
Step 4/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9faca0a1b18b
Step 5/8 : RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 080a6573557e
Step 6/8 : COPY . /app
 ---> e3a4e06df17f
Step 7/8 : ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
 ---> Running in d2f5f3063f28
Removing intermediate container d2f5f3063f28
 ---> 6d7e7b86fa12
Step 8/8 : CMD [ "app.py" ]
 ---> Running in fa149cc83cd1
Removing intermediate container fa149cc83cd1
 ---> 14e53a2402c8
Successfully built 14e53a2402c8
Successfully tagged fynd_task_app:latest
```

And image also built successfully but when I m trying to run the container on 5000 port where flask should be serving

```
sp@sp-H81M-S:~/Desktop/flask_app$ sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 fynd_task_app:latest
739eddd6a289a6949a498829314ca01b3c6ef41b60e7a0ad6d66badbfd9e9379
```

I think its container getting exited and there's nothing served on **localhost:5000**

here's the app.py code

```
import cv2 as cv
import argparse
import sys
import numpy as np
import os.path
import flask
import io
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications import imagenet_utils
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import render_template



confThreshold = 0.5  
nmsThreshold = 0.4   
inpWidth = 416      
inpHeight = 416
image_name = "uploaded.jpg"
image_dir = str(os.getcwd())


classesFile = "coco.names";
classes = None
with open(classesFile, 'rt') as f:
    classes = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

modelConfiguration = "yolov3.cfg";
modelWeights = "yolov3.weights";



app = flask.Flask(__name__)


net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(modelConfiguration, modelWeights)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)




def getOutputsNames(net):
    layersNames = net.getLayerNames()
    return [layersNames[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]




def drawPred(classId, conf, left, top, right, bottom):
    cv.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 178, 50), 3)

    label = '%.2f' % conf

    if classes:
        assert(classId < len(classes))
        label = '%s:%s' % (classes[classId], label)

    labelSize, baseLine = cv.getTextSize(label, cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 1)
    top = max(top, labelSize[1])
    cv.rectangle(frame, (left, top - round(1.5*labelSize[1])), (left + round(1.5*labelSize[0]), top + baseLine), (255, 255, 255), cv.FILLED)
    cv.putText(frame, label, (left, top), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (0,0,0), 1)






# Remove the bounding boxes with low confidence using non-maxima suppression
def postprocess(frame, outs):
    frameHeight = frame.shape[0]
    frameWidth = frame.shape[1]
    classIds = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []
    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            classId = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[classId]
            if confidence > confThreshold:
                center_x = int(detection[0] * frameWidth)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * frameHeight)
                width = int(detection[2] * frameWidth)
                height = int(detection[3] * frameHeight)
                left = int(center_x - width / 2)
                top = int(center_y - height / 2)
                classIds.append(classId)
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                boxes.append([left, top, width, height])

    indices = cv.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThreshold)
    for i in indices:
        i = i[0]
        box = boxes[i]
        left = box[0]
        top = box[1]
        width = box[2]
        height = box[3]
        drawPred(classIds[i], confidences[i], left, top, left + width, top + height)
        print("Prediction Box: {}:{}:{}:{}".format(left,top,width,height))




@app.route('/')
def render_static():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])

def predict():

    if flask.request.method == "POST":
        if flask.request.files.get("image"):

            file = flask.request.files["image"]
            file.save(image_name)
            frame = cv.imread(image_name)



            print(frame.shape)


            blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1/255, (inpWidth, inpHeight), [0,0,0], 1, crop=False)

            net.setInput(blob)

            outs = net.forward(getOutputsNames(net))

            classIds = []
            confidences = []
            boxes = []
            frameHeight = frame.shape[0]
            frameWidth = frame.shape[1]
            predictions = []


            for out in outs:
                for detection in out:
                    scores = detection[5:]
                    classId = np.argmax(scores)
                    confidence = scores[classId]
                    if confidence > confThreshold:
                        center_x = int(detection[0] * frameWidth)
                        center_y = int(detection[1] * frameHeight)
                        width = int(detection[2] * frameWidth)
                        height = int(detection[3] * frameHeight)
                        left = int(center_x - width / 2)
                        top = int(center_y - height / 2)
                        classIds.append(classId)
                        confidences.append(float(confidence))
                        boxes.append([left, top, width, height])
                        points = [left, top, left + width, top + height]
                        label = '%.2f' % confidence
                        if classes:
                            assert(classId < len(classes))
                            label = '%s:%s' % (classes[classId], label)
                        info = {"bounding_boxes" : points, "class" : label}

                        predictions.append(info)


            t, _ = net.getPerfProfile()
            label = 'Inference time: %.2f ms' % (t * 1000.0 / cv.getTickFrequency())



            cv.putText(frame, label, (0, 15), cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255))

            cv.imwrite("tested.jpg", frame.astype(np.uint8))






    return render_template("show.html", user_image = image_name,prediction = predictions)      
    # return flask.jsonify(predictions)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("* Loading Keras model and Flask starting server...")
    app.run()
```

where is the issue?

Comment: can you put also the code from app.py please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it runs on localhost (inside docker container), change it to 
`app.run(host='0.0.0.0')`. This tells your docker container to listen on a public IP ( so it can comunicate to docker container outside world) . ([doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application))